# Row data that acts as header for some row to become column data for those rows

Tags: excel, row, multiple-columns

In MS Excel
I have some data that has 'headers' and the actual info below it.
I would like to transpose the 'headers' into new columns for the actual info in order to use pivot tables.

**State** Georgia
**Code** 24
**County    Population Area** 
Fulton    1200       23 
Cobb      1943       47 
Gwinnett  5410       49 
Barrow    5231       10

**State** Massachusetts 
**Code**  36 
**County    Population Area**
Hampden   100       3 
Hampshire 143       7 
Berkshire 510       9
Worcester 531       1

To 

**State        Code County    Population Area**
Georgia       24   Fulton    1200       23
Georgia       24   Cobb      1943       47
Georgia       24   Gwinnett  5410       49
Georgia       24   Barrow    5231       10
**State        Code County    Population Area**
Massachusetts 36  Hampden   100       3
Massachusetts 36  Hampshire 143       7
Massachusetts 36  Berkshire 510       9
Massachusetts 36  Worcester 531       1

The number of rows as 'header' or actual 'info' may vary.

Comment: Do you need the solution to be completely within Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two columns (say A and B) on the left and a row at the top, If `24` is then in D3 enter:

in A2: `=IF(C2="State",D2,A1)`
in B2: `=IF(C2="Code",D2,B1)`

Copy both down to suit, select A:B, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, rearrange headers and delete any surplus.